# Diff/comparison tools for TFS/VS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, comparison

Merging conflicting code could be a nightmare, especially for formatted plain text files e.g. XML. The merging tool, [WinDiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff), that came with a Visual Studio really doesn't cut it for a even slightly more complicated difference.

It is pleasant to find that VS supports 3rd party comparison tools. I wonder which ones should I consider for a corporate?

I came across the [comparison page in wikipeiad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools), but the comparison is based on some documented features. Whereas I want to compare the intelligence of the algorithms.

So far, I have found the following ones (feel free to add more relevant ones).

- [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)
- [DiffMerge](http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)
- [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)
- [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)
- [Compare It](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm)

Please share your experience using comparison tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Araxis Merge Professional and i absolutely love it. It allows 3-Way merges in a way that you have Server Version, Client Version and the resulting merged Version in case of Source Control Conflicts for example. It's powerful because of tons of configuration options, pretty fast and a very well designed User Interface.

Good overview can be found here: [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html)

Guide for integrating Araxis Merge with Visual Studio can be found here: [Araxis Merge - Visual Studio Integration](http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html#VisualStudioTeamFoundation)

Comment: +1. Araxis is fabulous - but very expensive. A good second choice is Beyond compare - much cheaper. We use both at work (a couple of us do a lot of complex merging on folders, branches etc, and in this case Araxis is a must-have. The rest of the devs tend to just do simpler single-file check-in merges so they use BC). In general don't touch anything unless it offers 3-way merges.

Answer (score 3):

[DevArt CodeCompare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/) has a unique feature where it recognizes the actual code structure to make better code comparisons. It also does 3-way merge and integrates into Visual Studio including an editable diff view.

Answer (score 3):

Hands down for Beyond Compare, that's the one we use in our projects around here. I didn't have the opportunity to use these other compare tools mentioned but it is far, far, far better than the native SVN code compare. :)

It's not only a plain text compare, but also compare folders pretty easily (quite useful to compare branches, for instance).

As other compare tools mentioned, it also does the 3-way merging. And (I believe as other tools) can be integrated with SVN to be the default comparison tool.

I highly suggest it.

Comment: +1. A good solid diff/merge tool for a reasonable price